# I have to guess what set $I = \bigcap_{i\in N}(1−1/i,1)$ then prove at least one inlcusion.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Alright, we're on the subject of learning sets and how to prove them, and I'm seriously struggling with understanding the question. For one, I'm not sure what set it could be, or how to solve it. What's mostly tripping me up is how to read the question, can anyone help me understand what I'm looking at?
$$\bigcap_{i\in N}(1−1/i,1)$$

I do know that I do know that ⋂ is the intersection, and from what I'm reading, that particular symbol is saying 'all elements of I found in all sets N?' I also know I have to prove it by proving that one is a subset of the other and so on, but how do I deconstruct that?

Comment: When $i = 1$, you have the interval $(1-1,1) = (0,1)$.  When $i = 2$, you have the interval $(1-1/2,1) = (1/2,1)$.  When $i = 3$, you have the interval $(1-1/3,1) = (2/3,1)$.  And so on.  Then you intersect all (infinitely many of) those intervals as $i$ runs through the natural numbers, $1, 2, 3, \dots$.

Comment: @EricTowers Would the infinite intersection be $1$, or $\emptyset$?

Comment: @FShrike $1$ is a member of the infinite intersection iff it's a member of all of the intervals. Is that the case?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It is not the case, which is why I'm leaning toward $\emptyset$, but I thought perhaps that the intersection is, in the limit, arbitrarily close to $1$...? But I may well be mixing concepts here

Comment: The intersection asks for points that are in all those intervals.  Is $1$ in any of them?  If you pick an $x \in (0,1)$, can you find a choice of $i$ so that $x \not \in (1-1/i,1)$?  If you can find a recipe that goes from a choice of $x$ to an interval that excludes that $x$ from the intersection, you can exclude every possible point.

Comment: CherryK0re, what exactly do you have to prove, or find?

Comment: @FShrike According to the question, one inclusion. Which I'm fairly sure is supposed to be any equation? I haven't found anything about inclusions in my textbook other than the principle of inclusion-exclusion, which isn't in this chapter.

Comment: So, find one set which is a subset of: $$\bigcap_{i\in\Bbb N}\left(1-\frac{1}{i},1\right)$$?

Comment: Right. And because this is an infinite set (Is what I'm getting? It's not an empty set because there are infinite possibilities?), would that not mean I can plug any natural number into i and prove it?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure of this, but as I discussed with @EricTowers, the infinite intersection of all of these intervals is in fact the empty set, so without more clarity in your question... the answer should just be $\emptyset$

Comment: OH I think I may get it now. No matter what number you plug into i, you will never get a natural number, or even 1?

Comment: The set in question is the intersection of the sets {(0, 1), (1/2, 1), (2/3, 1), (3/4, 1), …(and so on)}. The intersection of any collection of sets refers to the set of elements that they all share in common. Also, note that (0, 1) doesn’t mean the set of numbers {0, 1}…it refers to the interval (0, 1) on the real line, aka all numbers between 0 and 1 (not inclusive). Similarly, (1/2, 1) refers to all real numbers between 1/2 and 1. Finally, for a concrete example, the intersection of (0, 1) and (1/2, 1) is (1/2, 1). Hope this clarifies things

Comment: @CherryK0re see answer below

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question and its comments thread, it seems like there may be a couple of basic misconceptions here, so let’s clear them up first!

- $N$ (properly typeset as $\mathbb{N}$) refers to the infinite set of natural numbers {1, 2, 3, …}.
- The symbol $\bigcap$ refers to the intersection of sets. For any two sets $A$ and $B$, $A \cap B$ refers to the set of elements that $A$ and $B$ have in common. If we have a collection of sets $\left\{A_1, A_2, …, A_n\right\}$, then $\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n A_i$ refers to the intersection of *all* of the sets in the collection.
- Note that $(1 - \frac{1}{i}, 1)$ refers to an **interval on the real line**, i.e. the set of all real numbers between $1 - \frac{1}{i}$ and $1$, exclusive. It is **not** the set $\left\{1 - \frac{1}{i}, 1\right\}$ (curly brackets), consisting of only the two elements $1 - \frac{1}{i}$ and $1$. For example, the number $\frac{2}{3}$ is inside the set $(0, 1)$, and is also inside the set $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ (and so must also be inside their intersection (0, 1) $\cap$ $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$.)

Finally, the question is asking what the set $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ $(1 - \frac{1}{i}, 1)$ is equivalent to. In other words, when you consider the infinite collection of sets/intervals
$$\left\{\left(1 - \frac{1}{1}, 1\right), \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}, 1\right), \left(1 -\frac{1}{3}, 1\right), …\right\},$$
what elements do they share in common?

The answer is **nothing**, i.e. the intersection is the empty set. This should make sense intuitively - as you go further and further down the collection, the intervals get narrower…in fact, infinitely narrow, such that there’s no elements to share anymore! A more formal proof could go as follows:

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$: Note that any element in the intersection must lie in the interval $(0, 1)$, since all intervals are included in this first interval. Consider *any* element/number $x \in (0, 1)$; we’ll show that $x$ is *not* included in one of the intervals in our collection. Let
$$N = \lceil \frac{1}{1-x} \rceil.$$
We claim that $x$ is *not* in the interval $(1 - \frac{1}{N}, 1)$. Indeed, we have that
$$ 
\begin{align*}
N \ge \frac{1}{1-x} &\Longrightarrow (1 - x)N \ge 1 \\
&\Longrightarrow N - xN \ge 1 \\
&\Longrightarrow xN \le N - 1 \\
&\Longrightarrow x \le \frac{N-1}{N} = 1 - \frac{1}{N}.
\end{align*}
$$

Thus, $x$ is not inside the intersection. But we have covered all elements $x \in (0, 1)$, which was our entire candidate range! Thus, there are no elements inside the intersection, i.e.
$$\bigcap\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (1 - \frac{1}{i}, 1) = \emptyset.$$

Comment: It took me a long while to understand this based on the mess of... well, being unprepared, but this is definitely concise and I finally get it! I knew the curly brackets meant it was not a set, though I supposed I must have confused it somewhere in the comment thread above ahah

Comment: Eh - what I meant with the curly brackets was like a discrete set, only consisting of the two elements “1 - 1/i” and “1”. It’s still a set, just not the set that the problem was referring to. Feel free to ask for clarifications on any of the notation!

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a set $A_i:=(1-\frac{1}{i}, 1)$, for each natural number $i$. We want to determine the set $\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i$, the set that contains the common elements of *all* $A_i$. A skratch work or an intellectual search would help us to realize that $\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i$ contains no elements -this is what we have to prove.

Let $\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i \neq \varnothing$. This means that there is an $x \in \bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i$. In other words there exists an $x\in A_i$, for all indices $i\in \Bbb N$, that is $\forall i\in \Bbb N: x\in (1-\frac{1}{i}, 1)$. By Archimedean Property for the positive $1-x$ exists a $N\in \Bbb N$, such that $\frac{1}{N}<1-x$ or $1-\frac {1}{N}>x$, which means that $x\notin (1-\frac{1}{N},1)$. So we found a natural index $i:=N$ such that $x\notin A_N$, which is impossible, because we have supposed that $x\in A_i$, for all $i\in \Bbb N$. Consequently $\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i=\varnothing$. q.e.d.